# numberPicker format while editing

Tags: android

I'm trying to use [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) to enter values in range 5.0..30.0, with step 0.1. So I set up its range as 50..300 and added a formatter. The upper and lower values are represented as I want, but the current one is represented without decimal point, like 200, and it confuses much.

Which listener should I add (and where) to force NumberPicker always format the current value? I tried to disable focusable, to disable children focusable, to set children[0] text using my formatter upon focus change… Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed that: [setDisplayedValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setDisplayedValues%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). That's what I needed.

Comment: This does seem to be a bug in the widget; but at least we have a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the workaround: instead of setting `mWidget.setFormatter(formatter)`,

```
String[] displayedValues = new String[mWidget.getMaxValue()-mWidget.getMinValue()+1];
for (int number = mWidget.getMinValue(); number<=mWidget.getMaxValue(); number++) {
    displayedValues[number-mWidget.getMinValue()] = formatter.format(number);
}
mWidget.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues);
```